# How can I verify SQLite Commands?

Tags: sqlite, if-statement, create-table, verify

I don't know how to verifiy SQLite commands in Android...
When I have that code:

```
final String CREATE_TABLE_USER =
                    "CREATE TABLE tbl_user ("
                    + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + "username VARCHAR(20));";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
```

I like to check "has been created":

```
if (tbl_user has been created)
```

How can I write that?
Eclipse says I can't convert a void to a boolean...

Answer (score 1):

An exception will be thrown if the SQL statement fails to execute. That means that if the code normally following the `db.execSQL(...)` runs, the SQL was executed correctly. Easy!

Consider using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_user (...)` if you're worried about the potential for the table to already exist.

---

[EDIT]: If you want to check whether the create exists, you need to trap the exception:

```java
try {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    doMessage("made the tbl_user table");
} catch (SQLException exn) {
    doMessage("did not make the tbl_user table: " + exn.getMessage());
    throw exn; // Let the exception propagate as we're just reporting...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;) But I still implemented the "IF NOT EXISTS"... I think my question is not clear enough. I like to give out an alert with "Table tbl_user has been created" or "Table tbl_user has not been created because of anything..." For that I have to check that by an if..

Comment: @user1085392: But `if` is the wrong way to do it. Use `try` as I show above.

Comment: Very nice :D Thanks. I think that's it. Just one problem left: SQLException cannot be resolved to a type. 
Painful... Had to import the SQLException package.

Problem has been cleared :) Thanks guys!

Comment: @user1085392: I think it's the superclass of SQLiteException. Can't remember as I've closed that window now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If creating the table fails, an Exception will be thrown. So if the creation doesn't throw an exception you can be pretty darn sure the table exists.